# Why do these Google search result counts appear to be inconsistent?

Tags: google-search

I was reading about options (the financial instruments), and found that both "option expiration date" and "option expiry date" are commonly used terms for the same thing. I decided I would use Google search result counts to try and get a quick sense of which term is more widely used.

So here are the searches I did:

---

**1:** [`option expiration date`](https://www.google.ca/search?site=&source=hp&q=option+expiration+date&oq=option+expiration+date&gs_l=hp.3..35i39j0l3j0i20j0l4.5726.7705.0.7776.23.19.0.0.0.0.158.1923.9j9.18.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.hp..6.17.1849.0.Gz5PHf6jIwY): **45,700,000**

[image: option-search-1-option-expiration-date]

---

**2:** [`option expiry date` (Including results for `option expiration date`)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=option+expiry+date&oq=option+expiry+date&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0i10l5j0i20l2j0i10j0.21812.22509.0.22604.7.7.0.0.0.2.126.615.5j2.7.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.serp..2.5.420.sTIcDwV3M6I): **14,200,000**

[image: option-search-2-option-expiry-date-including-option-expiration-date]

---

**3:** [`option expiry date` (Search only for `option expiry date`)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=option+expiry+date&nirf=option+expiration+date&sa=X&ei=H3vVVPjqEIHpgwTH_4PYCw&ved=0CBwQ8BYoAQ&biw=1920&bih=941): **85,200,000**

[image: option-search-3-only-option-expiry-date]

---

You don't need a degree in computer science to see that there's something wrong with those numbers. If (truncating now for concision) `expiration=45M` and `expiry=85M`, then how can `expiry+expiration=14M`?

In general, can Google search result counts be relied upon to indicate ascendancy of terms?

(Note: I originally posted this on Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378063/why-do-these-google-search-result-counts-appear-to-be-inconsistent, but got ripped to shreds for being off-topic, and now I've finally discovered Super User, which seems to be more appropriate for this question. Sorry for the duplicate post, and feel free to educate me on which sites should be used for which topics, or whatever.)

Comment: It is off topic here too IMO. Did you read the help section of either site as they will help you to see what is [on / off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)? SuperUser and StackOVerflow are both part of Stack Exchange, you can't cross post (put the post on both) so please delete one of them

Comment: Well damnit man! Is it on-topic anywhere? Have I found a hole in the universe?

Comment: I just 'closed' your SO question by casting the final vote. How do you think any one could answer this? I suspect the only ones who know are those who study Google, or, Google!!! You may get luck in the 'chat' section of webmasters http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Dave This is an excellent question. There *must* be a reason why Google's search result numbers don't stack up. Someone out there may well know why this is the case.

Comment: Thank you @misha256! Now I feel like less of an idiot. (grrr, @Dave)

Comment: Of course there are always discrepanceies - jsut a few minute later I get (which depends on my geolocation as well as what Google calls personalized serach results) 88.1M, 20M, 45M

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good point. Decided to try myself, I get very similar results to OP (44.4M, 13.8M, 84M).

Comment: @misha256, I never said the question wasn't good, I said I don't think it's on topic based upon the help pages which define what is on/off topic. This has nothing to do with the PC for example, and may be more suited to webapps

Comment: @Dave That's quite true, my misunderstanding sorry! Hmm, it's one of those gray/grey areas I think. But my view is that the OP isn't interested in coding or developing web apps, he's interested in understanding why his end-user experience of a popular web app is returning inconsistent results. It's about the same as someone asking "why are Excel calculations behaving inconsistently in these scenarios" which is very much on topic here.

Comment: Google's mechanics are a trade secret.  Even if somebody did know the answer they are unlikely are able to share it.  This cannot be answered.

Comment: @misha256, yes, a web app!! Hence why it may be better suited there. Coupled with my comment of "How do you think any one could answer this unless they are Google", which is also backed up by Ramhound's comment - no, it's off topic, and I don't think it can belong on the SE sites... Better to ask on some forum I'm sorry to say (this isn't me being difficult, these are the rules of the site, not my rules) :(

Comment: http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/585/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I decided I would use Google search result counts to try and get a quick sense of which term is more widely used.

Don't do that.  It has long since been debunked as a linguistic methodology.

Google's mechanics may be trade secrets, but we have Google employees on the record saying that **these numbers are estimates**, and indeed the Google API doco itself explicitly said so some years ago.  Common sense also says so.  (Some people apparently think that for every search that happens, Google's system actually goes and *counts* millions of pages.  That would be an inefficient and slow way of going about things.  These are *not counts*.)  These "hit counts" are a meaningless metric.  Do not rely upon them.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2008). [*Google result counts are a meaningless metric.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/google-result-counts-are-a-meaningless-metric.html)  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Who exactly is `Jonathan de Boyne Pollard`?  What sort of authority does he have?  I can't find any connection to him and Google.  I feel this answer could simply be reduced down to the estimates displayed are only estimates likely based on the results that people ended up clicking.